# Relabelling in prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I am trying to relabel after copying the existing metrics for Kafka only for the below match:

```
Kafka_log_size{partition=“1”, topic=“ab_bc_cd_12345_ef_001”,} 10
```

I want output as:

```
Kafka_log_size{partition=“1”, topic=“ab_bc_cd_12345_ef_001”,} 10
Kafka_log_size_uniq{partition=“1”, uniq=“12345”,} 10
```

From reading multiple articles, it seems this can be achieved by relabeling but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: I was checking some more options towards it , is it possible to have output as :                           Kafka_log_size{partition=“1”, topic=“ab_bc_cd_12345_ef_001”, uniq=“12345”, } 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options to relabel your metrics in Prometheus:

- at ingestion time using [metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) (in Prometheus configuration)
- at request time using [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace)

In both cases, you need to have a regex that matches the content of `topic` label and extracts what you need.

**Relabeling in config**

In your job scraping for Kafka, you have to match the metric name you want to replace and [use relabeling config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config):

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [topic] 
    regex: '[a-z_]+_([0-9]+)_.*'
    action: replace
    target_label: uniq
    replacement: $1
```

And then add a rule to drop the label

```
  - regex: 'topic'
    action: droplabel
```

**Relabeling in request**

The new label is generated using label replace:

```
label_replace(Kafka_log_size, "uniq", "$1", "topic", "[a-z_]+_([0-9]+)_.*")
```

And then, apply an [aggregation operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) to remove the unwanted label:

```
max(label_replace(Kafka_log_size, "uniq", "$1", "topic", "[a-z_]+_([0-9]+)_.*")) without(topic)
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, I tried with relabelling request and it worked . I want to try with 1st opton you mention , so I can write both relabelling config rules one after other in configuration yaml file ?